# AWS CodeDeploy - deploy using the incorrect revision files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

been banging my head against the wall trying to get an unbelievably simple CodeDeploy run going. The behavior I'm seeing suggests either a configuration issue or an issue local to the running agent. Basically, deployments are *not* using the files explicitly supplied to them - they're stuck implicitly using a prior version.

Having created an application and deployment group (and ensuring all prerequisites are in place such as the agent and roles are correctly assigned), I'm creating a deployment with via zipping up my code folder (at the root, not including the code's containing folder). There were a few issues to fix in a few of the hook steps, but I was able to fix a couple of them by changing the code, re-zipping and re-uploading before things got particularly weird. There was a syntax issue in my ApplicationStart hook script (when I finally got that far), so I fixed it and re-uploaded as before. However, the same syntax error occurred. I tried re-uploading, deleting all my S3 files and re-uploading, downloading the listed revision files and checking their contents (changes were reflected), but the same syntax error occurred. I even deleted the script and hook step completely from the yml file and it still happened, so clearly the deployment system is "stuck" in some sense. I went as far as feeding it a completely empty text file, told it it was a `tar` file, and it's still running my old revision. It's as though the runner agent's local files are stale and it's failing to clear local contents.

What's the deal? I feel like I've missed something fundamental.

**edit** - I created an entirely identical but new deployment group and re-tried the deployment with my new files and it worked. So that *deployment group* itself is stuck.

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out?  I am having exactly the same problem just now.

Comment: I have even deleted the revision in the S3 bucket, but I still get the error messages related to the old version.

Comment: For anyone else with this problem, it is explained by the accepted answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192414/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-clean-slate-deployment-with-aws-codedeploy?rq=1, which references the following:

[1]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeployment.html#CodeDeploy-CreateDeployment-request-ignoreApplicationStopFailures

[2]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-deployments-lifecycle-event-failures

Comment: The explanation is that the application_stop event uses the code from the last installation,  presumably because that is what is being stopped.  This caused me confusion because I was changing the event code and seeing no difference.  The other events use the code from the latest revision.